# How to change schemalocation in an xsd file so that it refers another xsd file from classpath?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, ant, build

The server on which we are deploying our jar file doesn't have internet connection.

When I am making a runnable jar from eclipse and deploy/run everything works fine
but when I use ant to build the jar from same code base and I get the following exception :-

```
2015-01-22 02:26:37 WARN  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:48 - Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///C:/TMC_SERVICE/spring-context-4.1.xsd; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 110; schema_reference.
4: Failed to read schema document '../spring-tool-4.1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) th
e root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

I have kept spring-beans, spring-context, spring-utils and spring-tools in my classpath. Have also changed the schemalocation in the spring-context file but still it's failing.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If all the schema's in the same location, then you can just refer it by schema file name. Are you doing the referencing schemas using relative path?

Comment: I am referencing schema's using `file:///` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

For the spring schemas specifically you don't need to do anything clever - just declare them with their usual `http:` locations. When parsing bean definition files spring uses a catalog to redirect requests for the known spring schemas to cached copies inside the spring jar files.